# How can i do a like kind CAML queries - SharePoint 2013

Tags: caml-query

I have a text e.g AOCup and i need it to match AO Cup

Where currentsite variable below  is = AOCup but what im querying is AO Cup

Thanks in Advance

** I also used Contain with no luck

```
 <Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + currentSite + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using below query:

```
<Query><Where><Contains>
     <FieldRef Name='Title' />
     <Value Type='Text'>AO</Value>
  </Contains></Where></Query>
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik but i tried using just contain and had no luck

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing as like in caml queries but you could try it with an AND connection and a  condition, something like this:

```
<Query><Where><And><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + AO + "</Value></Contains>
<Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Cup + "</Value></Contains>
<And></Where></Query>
```